# How to declare an array inline in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, literals

I am looking for the VB.NET equivalent of

```
var strings = new string[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
Dim strings() As String = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}
```

Comment: Not too sure I like the array indicator on the variable name, it goes against common convention. Especially in other languages.

Comment: @ganjeii Not all languages: C for example, but also and more importantly in this case VBA, only accept this syntax for array declaration

Comment: Note that as inferred in the next answer these two are equivalent:

`Dim strings() As String`
`Dim strings As String()`

Answer (score 46):

There are plenty of correct answers to this already now, but here's a "teach a guy to fish" version.

First create a tiny console app in C#:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var strings = new string[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    }
}
```

Compile it, keeping debug information:

```
csc /debug+ Test.cs
```

Run [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on it, and open up the Main method - then decompile to VB. You end up with:

```
Private Shared Sub Main()
    Dim strings As String() = New String() { "abc", "def", "ghi" }
End Sub
```

So we got to the same answer, but without actually knowing VB. That won't always work, and there are plenty of other conversion tools out there, but it's a good start. Definitely worth trying as a first port of call.

Comment: I agree that Reflector should be in every .NET developers tool belt. But for this it would be simpler to use the online converter at http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: This is good for specifying that `{Nothing}` is an array of `String` or basically any other type, as opposed an array of `Object`, which a compiler will assume in *certain particular scenarios* if you don't include `New String() ` before the contents.

Answer (score 10):

In newer versions of VB.NET that support type inferring, this shorter version also works:

```
Dim strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim strings As String() = New String() {"abc", "def", "ghi"}
```

Comment: Ah, but this did help me pass in an inline declaration to a function:
  MyFunction(somestring, New String() {"abc", "def", "ghi"})

Answer (score 5):

Not a VB guy. But maybe something like this?

```
Dim strings = New String() {"abc", "def", "ghi"}
```

(About 25 seconds late...)

Tip: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 4):

`Dim strings As String() = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}`