# vb.net: list of typed class, how to add items like C#?

Tags: .net, vb.net, declaration, generic-list

in vb.net I have this class:

```
public Class Articulo
  Public Id As Integer
  Public Name As Integer
  Public Precio As Double
End Class
```

You know with C# we can add items like:

```
List<Articulo> list = new List<Articulo>();

list.add(new Articulo() {
  Id = 1,
  Name="xxx1"
});

list.add(new Articulo() {
  Id = 2,
  Name="xxx2"
});
```

Is it possible to do it in vb.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305505/how-to-do-array-creation-in-vb-net-using-object-initializers-to-set-properties/16305567#16305567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible using the `With` keyword:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Articulo)()

list.add(New Articulo() With {.Id = 1, .Name="xxx1"})

list.add(New Articulo() With {.Id = 2, .Name="xxx2"})
```

Comment: You can also add an anonymouse type : list.add(New  With {.Id = 1, .Name="xxx1"})